# Algorithm to use for fluid order

Tags: optimization, knapsack-problem, bin-packing

I am looking for an algorithm to use to help with fluid orders.  I believe it may be a version or the knapsack or bin packibg problems.

We have say 5 storage tanks, 3 of them are product a, 2 of them are product b.

The tanks can be different capacities.

We have historical data telling us roughly how much will be used from each tank while awaiting delivery of new product.  The supplied product comes in a fixed quantity, although multiples of the supply quantity can be purchased.

There is a minimum quantity that can be ordered- the minimum can be a combination of products or all the same.  We want to stock the minimum of each product that we can, but still meet the demand we predict from each tank.  The tanks are not linked and product cannot be pumped between tanks even though it is the same product.

If I can find out the algorithm I need, I should be able to code it with too much problem.  Thanks

Comment: Sounds like an interview question! Base on the history you have, can you make a weight tree from them and calculate the possibility. I am thinking using the Huffman algorithm to solve it!

Comment: Let U = how much will be used from the tank (your estimate based on historical usage). Let C = how much is currently in the tank. Therefore, the tank needs U-C product. I don't see a bin packing connection.

Comment: The minimum orders create the problem.  It's not an interview problem - it's a real world case for my current problem - if it helps were talking about petrol/gas and diesel, the historical data is usage from the pumps connected to each tank.  Some tanks feed more pumps therefore get more use.  But you cannot overfill a tank (not even a little bit) but to get any delivery you need to take the minimum order.  Obviously we don't want to dump a huge order into a tank that does not see much use, as that ties up huge amounts of capital.

Comment: Adam - the problem is packing the minimum order into the tanks, with priority given to the tanks that see the most usage, not necessarily the tank that has the most capacity.